# How to append regex capture group with number in pd.df.replace?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to replace the last digit of fixed length digit sequence with 0 in pandas dataframe column.

Using r'\10' tries to reference 10th capture group, even though I would like to take first capture group and add '0' to it.

Inserting space like r'\1 0' makes the program run, but the end result has the extra space present.

```py
df['column'] = '12345'
df['column'].replace({r'(\d{4})\d': r'\1 0'}, regex=True)
df['column']
-> '1234 0'
```

How should I modify my code to get output of something like `12340`?

Comment: The unambiguous backreference syntax is `\g<GROUP_ID>`

Comment: you can achieve your desired result with regular expression.

df['column'] = df.column.str[:-1] + '0'